# Login with different user using amplify_auth_cognito for flutter

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, amplify-flutter, amplify-auth-cognito

When using

```dart
await Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(provider: AuthProvider.google);
```

to sign in and

```dart
await Amplify.Auth.signOut();
```

to sign out,

If I sign in, the very first time I am prompted to select a google account.
Then if I sign out, every time I try sign in again, it succeeds silently without allowing me to select a different google account.

What I'm looking for, is when I sign out and the user goes back to sign in, they're taken back through the google account selection process.

Using

```yaml
dependencies:
  amplify_flutter: 1.0.0-next.0+3
  amplify_auth_cognito: 1.0.0-next.0+5
```